# Как отключить в chrome автоподстановку в input с типов password

Tags: html, вёрстка, frontend, forms

Есть HTML форма на бутстрапе. В ней есть 2 тега input, у первого type="email"   у второго type="password". Если  инпуту с типом password задать еще не пустой атрибут name, то в гугл хром после загрузки страницы у обоих инпутов становиться фон желтым и инпуту с типом email присваивается значение "admin", а в инпут с типом password заполняется какой то пароль. 
Как от этого избавиться ?  autocomplate = "off" не помагает.

Comment: Никак... честно, вот никак. Они на столько навязчиво включили эту функцию, что все способы описанные в интернете попросту не помогают.

Comment: В обще жесть(( кто их просил... смотрится ни к селу ни к городу.

Comment: кстати на hh.ru они как то это побороли

Comment: autocomplate или autocomplete?

Comment: autocomplete="off"

Comment: у меня работало только с autocomplete="false"

Answer (score 2):

У меня работают следующие способы вместе:

1. autocomplete="false" у формы
2. value='****' у инпутов, а в onload стирать (у какого-то браузера была логика не переписывать заполненные поля).
3. setTimeout со стиранием значений через доли секунды после загрузки.

Answer (score 2):

В общем помогло следующее:
ставим в input с типом password атрибут readonly и прописываем в него onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');

```
<input type="password" class="form-control input-lg"  name="password"  placeholder="Ваш пароль"  required="required" autocomplete="off" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" >
```

Правда после этого он принимает цвет неактивного элемента, поэтому ему нужно задать стили которые сделают ему нормальный фон, например:

```
#auth_form input {
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

Правда такой подход не гарантирует, что с выходом новой версии какого либо браузера в нем это не перестанет работать (ровно как и все остальные).

Comment: а если снимать атрибут readonly после загрузки?

Comment: пробовал, не вышло, тот метод, который я описал, оказался единственно рабочим на тот момент. Правда setinterval я не делал.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло это:

```html
<!-- Хак для Хрома, который заполняет пустую пару логин/пароль -->
<div style="width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden"><input type="text"><input type="password"></div>
```

autocomplete="off" не помог, обертка с "display: none;" тоже не помогла.

Answer (score 0):

В Mozilla работает атрибут - autocomplete="new-password"

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос